# How to c# List<> order by and Group by according to parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

I have a class and its List

```
 abc cs = new abc();
 List<abc> Lst_CS = new List<abc>();
```

and I set some value by HidenField in `foreach` loop

```
 foreach (blah blah)
        {
 cs = new abc{
                    No = VKNT,
                    GuidID=hdnGuidID.Value.ToString(),
                    RecID=hdnRecID.Value.ToString(),
                    Date=HdnDate.Value.ToString()                    
                    };
                    Lst_CS.Add(cs);
}
```

and finally I get a List_CS and I order by Lst_CS according to `Date` like this;

```
 IEnumerable<abc> query = Lst_CS.OrderBy(l => l.Date).ToList();
```

but in extra, I want to group by according to `No`.

Briefly, I want to order by `Date` and then group by `No` on `Lst_CS` How can I do ?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: `Lst_CS.OrderBy(l => l.Date).GroupBy(l=>l.No)` Am I missing something?

Comment: I try this of course, but I get this error:"An explicit conversion exist(are you missing a cast)?" I think it cannot convert  List to IEnumerable

Comment: Just replace your `IEnumerable<abc> query` with `var query`. Your debugger will show you the type it returns..

Comment: but I try only order by its no problem like this:     IEnumerable<abc> query = Lst_CS.OrderBy(l => l.Date).ToList();

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList` if you are then storing it in an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @jeremmyp your result will not be an `IEnumerable<abc>` but an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<abc>>` - essentially a collection of _groupings_, each of which contains a collection of `abc`s.  That's why you're getting the cast error.

Comment: @DStanley  I try this :     `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, abc>> groups = Lst_CS.OrderBy(l => l.Date).GroupBy(l =>l.No);` but how can get data in foreach loop I try this but not working:  `foreach (abc CS in groups)` . I get This error: "Unable to cast object of type 'Grouping"

Comment: @jeremmyp that's how grouping works - each item is an `IGrouping` that contains the key and a list of items in each group. Maybe if you explained better what output you want (what do you mean by "grouping") we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well you just just do the ordering then the grouping like so:

```
Lst_CS.OrderBy(l => l.Date)
      .GroupBy(l => l.No)
      .ToList();
```

Each list of items in each group will be ordered by date.  The *groupings* will be in the order that they are found when the entire list is ordered by date.

Also your `ForEach` can be done in one Linq statement, then combined with the ordering and grouping:

```
var query = blah.Select(b => new abc{
                        No = VKNT,
                        GuidID=hdnGuidID.Value.ToString(),
                        RecID=hdnRecID.Value.ToString(),
                        Date=HdnDate.Value.ToString()                    
                        })
                 .OrderBy(l => l.Date)
                 .GroupBy(l => l.No)
                 .ToList();
```